# datetime comparaison doctrine querybuilder

Tags: symfony, datetime, doctrine, query-builder

I want to delete all the entries from my database where the ending date is reached

```
 $em = $this->getEntityManager();
            $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('f');
            $qb->delete('AcmeMyBundle:FlowerEntity');
            $qb->where($qb->expr()->lte('f.endingDate', ':now'));
            $qb->setParameter('now', new \DateTime('now'));

            return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I get the error

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 57: Error: Expected end of string, got 'f'
```

I tried many ways but unfortunately without much success.. Any clues ? Thanks !

---

SOLUTION based on NHG answer

```
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->delete('AcmeMyBundle:FlowerEntity', 'f');
    $qb->where($qb->expr()->lte('f.endingDate', ':now'));
    $qb->setParameter('now', new \DateTime('now'));

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont't know what is your definition of `endingDate` field, but you could try to convert a `DateTime` object to string:

```
$date = new \DateTime('now');
// query
$qb->setParameter('now', $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s'));
```

**EDIT:**

So problem is with `f` argument in `$em->createQueryBuilder('f')`. Try:

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
            $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $qb->delete('AcmeMyBundle:Flower', 'f');
// further code
```

[Doc.](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.QueryBuilder.html#567) Additionaly I used `Flower` instead of `FlowerEntity`.

Comment: endingDate is a dateTime too , how can i change that one into string? i've tried f.endingDate->format( .. ) in the query but it throw expected parameter 1 to be object boolean given (it looked so dirty i hesitated to try this lol )

Answer (score 0):

you can compare by Datetime like this:

```
$qb->where('f.endingDate <= :minDatetime');
$qb->setParameter('minDatetime', $minDatetime);
```